# PostgreSQL C++11 library for windows and linux

Tags: postgresql, c++11, libpqxx

could you recommend me some library to access PostgreSQL database from linux and windows? I need version of c++11 which eliminates libpqxx which needs C++20.

Thank you

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic on SO. You could try the Software Recommendations sibling site

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I didnt know that there is this site.

Comment: This isn't really a recommendation question IMHO. As the poster states, the problem is that the official C++ API to PostgreSQL requires support for modern C++. So he is really asking how to interface PostgreSQL when you have to use C++11. I assume one solution might be to just use the C API - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html I'm lucky enough to be able to use the PostgreSQL support in Qt5 (as suggested).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of C library. I´ve already tried that and it looks that it works fine. There are only some drawbacks through some problems with a multiprocess approach in the library but it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more lightweight libraries for the purpose but I'm personally using the Qt solution here.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html